# Android Google + integration sometimes return null values

Tags: android, google-plus

In my application i am using Google Plus integration. Also access Google account details include username, profile image etc. But these user details some times return null value. Please help me to find the reason.

This is my code:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(MainActivity.this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(MainActivity.this).addApi(Plus.API,Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
```

and in onConnected():

```
   @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

            String personName="Unknown";

                gmail = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(
                        (GoogleApiClient) mGoogleApiClient).toString();
                try {

                    String[] id = gmail.split("@");
                    try {
                        plusid = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient).getId();
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        plusid = id[0];
                    }

                    plusimage = Plus.PeopleApi
                            .getCurrentPerson((GoogleApiClient) mGoogleApiClient)
                            .getImage().getUrl().toString();

                    plusname = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient).getDisplayName().toString();

                }
                if (CheckNetworkConnection.isConnectionAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
                 //   new SocialLogin().execute();
                }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GMAIL" + gmail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID" +plusid , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NAME" + plusname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IMG" + plusimage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google plus account not configured correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
```

here plusimage and plusname return null.Please help me to find the reason.

Comment: Without providing us any code, it'll be quite difficult to find where in your code the issue is coming from. Please read these docs - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - before asking a question.

Comment: @jeffdill2 Sorry.Question  Edited

Comment: @krishna use this example for reference may be it work for you.. https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java#L51-L55

Answer (score 1):

Add this line.

```
 Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);
```

like.

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {    

    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);

    String personName="Unknown";
    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
       Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
       String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
       String personPhoto = currentPerson.getImage();
       String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
    }
}
```

for more info. read [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people)

Comment: this also return null value

Comment: @krishna Is SHA1 the same between your app and the google console ?

Comment: // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
// profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

Comment: then
 // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
 // options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

Comment: Thanks all..i don't know why but now the same code above works perfectly.